# NullpointerException when create session between Apache Spark and Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Apache Spark 2.1.0 and Cassandra 3.0.14. In my code I want to create a connection between Spark and Cassandra:

```
            ...
 SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
     .appName(appName)
     .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")                            
     .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", 9042)
     .getOrCreate();

CassandraConnector cassandraConnector = CassandraConnector
     .apply(sparkSession.sparkContext().getConf()); 
Session session = cassandraConnector.openSession();
ResultSet rs = session.execute("select * from myDB.myTable");
            ...
```

When I run the code locally in eclipse everything works fine, but when I run the jar-file on my local spark server I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The method which causes this error is

```
cassandraConnector.openSession();
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xign_analysis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xign_analysis_jar_archive</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Im using Macbook with El Capitan (10.11.06 ). My Spark Master, Spark Worker and Cassandra server are running fine. I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems I get no connection because Cassandra is running on localhost:9042. So the method `cassandraConnector.openSession()` returns **null**.  Is there another way to configure cassandra host and port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the **spark/jars** dir there is an older version of **Guava: Google Core Libraries For Java**. I replaced this older version (v. 14.0.1) with the newest one (v. 23.0) and everything works fine.